# File Size is 0 byte (Download File Application with Struts2 And MySQL)

Tags: mysql, download, struts2

Firstly, I uploaded a file to MySQL as BLOB type. I can view the content of that file by using Open Value in Editor of MySQL DB. Then I downloaded that file and there is no content and file size is 0 byte.

My Code is as following :

**JSP**

```
<td align="center"> <s:url action="downloadFile" var="urlTag" escapeAmp="false"><s:param name="work_id"><s:property value="%{#request.workid}"/></s:param> </s:url> 
<a href="<s:property value="#urlTag" />">Download</a><br> </td>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<action name="downloadFile" class="com.sales.action.DownloadFileAction">
<result name="success" type="stream">
<param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
<param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
<param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${fileName}"</param>
<param name="bufferSize">4096</param>
</result>
</action>
```

**Action.java**
public class DownloadFileAction extends ActionSupport {

```
private InputStream inputStream;
private String fileName;
private int work_id;
private long contentLength;

public DownloadFileAction() {

}

public int getWork_id() {
    return work_id;
}

public void setWork_id(int work_id) {
    this.work_id = work_id;
}

public void setInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
    this.inputStream = inputStream;
}

public void setContentLength(long contentLength) {
    this.contentLength = contentLength;
}

public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public long getContentLength() {
    return contentLength;
}

public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}

public InputStream getInputStream() {
    return inputStream;
}

public String execute() throws Exception {
    DevWorkInfoDAO dao = new DevWorkInfoDAO();
    List tmp = new ArrayList();
    tmp = dao.fileDownload(work_id);

    fileName = tmp.get(0).toString();
    Blob b = (Blob) tmp.get(1);

    inputStream = b.getBinaryStream();

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

}

**DAO.java**

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM salesmanagementsystem.devorder_file_tbl where id_devorder = "+work_id;

System.out.println(sql);

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

while (rs.next()) {

DevOrder_File_Tbl dev = new DevOrder_File_Tbl();

dev.setId(rs.getInt("id"));

dev.setFile_name(rs.getString("name_file"));

dev.setFile(rs.getBlob("file"));

tmp.add(dev);

}

return tmp;
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: How can I get the original file from MySQL Blob Type?

Comment: If you've found an answer to your question then answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In struts.xml , dont forget to write the contentLength.

```
<param name="contentLength">contentLength</param>
```